# Do we require 10 different ports to run 10 clients

Tags: node.js, angular, spring

Recently I was exploring node and angular. Got to know that node will be running in 3000 port in local developer machine by default. My doubt is, do we require 10 different ports to run 10 different clients at same time in local machine?

Comment: yes  you always require it

Comment: What is client here? Node is running at port 3000, is node the client or the server? If it is the latter you can connect multiple times to that port. If you want to run 10 instances of node on the same port, that isn't possible.

Comment: Node is the client here. It need not be same port, say I want to run 3 clients in my machine so, I can configure clients to run on 3000,8080,5000 etc. but I imagine it will be problem if I want to run 10's of clients in parallel !? PS : I'm just trying to understand the concept here, pls expect mistakes/misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

Each TCP/IP *connection* is described by the combination of Server IP/Server Port and Client IP/Client Port. So this set of 4 values must be unique for each connection.

The Server IP/Server Port are the same for each connection to a single service (this is the 3000 number that you mention). The client port is selected (effectively at random) each time a connection is opened.

So you **don't need to listen on 10 ports to be able to let 10 clients connect** to the server.